# React Native, passing locale parameter from i18next to Axios config file gives Invalid hook call error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios

I'm trying to implement a locale parameter into my axiosConfig file:

```
import axios from "axios";

const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://10.0.2.2:8000/api",
  timeout: 2000,
});

instance.defaults.headers.common["locale"] = "en";

export default instance;
```

On each screen I make my get and post calls on screens as such:

```
axiosConfig
      .get("/someroute")
      .then((response) => {
        //console.log(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.message);
      });
```

The above code works as intended. Now I want to pass a "locale" parameter into all of my axios calls. This parameter will come from app locale (i use i18next). When I implement it as below, it throws an invalid hook error.

```
import axios from "axios";
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";

const { i18n } = useTranslation();

const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://10.0.2.2:8000/api",
  timeout: 2000,
});

instance.defaults.headers.common["locale"] = i18n.language;

export default instance;
```

What would be the correct way to set the locale header in my configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error because a hook should be called in a React Component or inside another hook. See [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html). And here is what you could do for example:

1. Transform the file where you are setting the axios instance to a hook:

```js
import axios from "axios";
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";

const useAxiosInstance = ()=>{
  const { i18n } = useTranslation();

  const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://10.0.2.2:8000/api",
    timeout: 2000,
  });
  instance.defaults.headers.common["locale"] = i18n.language;
  
  return instance;
}
export default useAxiosInstance;
```

2. You include the hook at the top of the file where you are using the axios config and use it as an example this way:

```js
import {useEffect} from "react";
import useAxiosConfig from "./path";

const AxiosConsumer = ()=>{
 const axiosConfig = useAxiosConfig();
 
 useEffect(()=>{
   axiosConfig
    .get("/someroute")
    .then((response) => {
    //console.log(response.data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error.message);
    });
  },[axiosConfig]);
  
  return <></>
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, i cant seem to get the content to load, how would i call on AxiosConsumer in my file? VScode also says ``` 'AxiosConsumer' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)```

Comment: You don't need to have `AxioConsumer`. I added that as an example. You just need to add this line `const axiosConfig = useAxiosConfig();` where you used to use `axiosConfig`.

Comment: fyi: you can also just import the i18next instance and get the resolvedLanguage: https://www.i18next.com/overview/api#resolvedlanguage